# Infinite dials to reset ever?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, time

I have an infinite number of dials with red needles that rotate $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ times every second. They all start pointing North.

> Will they simultaneously all point North ever again?

Comment: Obviously should have been answered by @North :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer

> Yes, after one second, since each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$